# Query optimization in Django

Tags: python, django, query-optimization, django-queryset

Hi I have a query to the Database something like this

```
qset = Database_View.objects.filter(xx__name__icontains=tata)
qset = qset.filter(xx__name__icontains=dada)
qset = qset.filter(xx__name__icontains=papa)
```

How can I make it into one single query?

Comment: `Database_View.objects.filter(xx__name__icontains=tata).filter(xx__name__icontains=dada).filter(xx__name__icontains=papa)`

Comment: Querysets are lazy. It already is one single query.

Comment: @MarkGalloway is right. Your queryset won't get evaluated until you use it.

Comment: If you are looking for a one liner, just put everything under one `filter` clause separated by `,`

Answer (score 0):

This would already be one query as django gives us the provision of lazy loading in querysets. So in your database there would only be one select query for fetching the results. You can read more about lazy loading of django [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/optimization/)

Comment: please don't just post a link here. Provide a sufficient answer